# Suggestions for fixing bottom of concrete step

Tags: concrete, stairs

Part of the bottom of the side of my concrete step is crumbling away and I'm looking for advice on a reasonably quick and easy fix as I'm worried critters will get in there (if they aren't already).  My current (and potentially misguided idea) is potentially making some forms, mixing up some concrete and pushing it into the gap with the forms.

Any suggestions/help with this would be much appreciated :).

[image: Steps]
[image: Zoomed Steps]
[image: Steps 2]
[image: Zoomed steps 2]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What's behind/underneath the steps? (And, your initial idea sounds good to me.)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, and thanks for the response :).  I added a couple more pictures for perspective.  The only access in behind the steps is via this hole so I can't really tell what's in behind.  I pushed a broom handle about half way to 2/3rds of the way in and it appears as though there is at least some hollow space.

Comment: Your plan sounds good, but I would add a step.  Use some kind of pole to keep pushing concrete into the hole and packing it to fill the hole.  Then use the forms to make the edge look pretty,

Comment: I like that idea, I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: Another option would be to use a can of expanding foam. Blow it in, let it expand to fill the void, cut it flush with the step, and then paint. This should keep animals out, and be a lot easier, cheaper, and faster than concrete.

Comment: @StephenMeschke That's a good idea for a quick fix.  I ended up going the concrete route but I'll have to keep the spray foam idea in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.  I ended up using concrete and some pieces of scrap wood as make shift forms.  I also pushed some concrete back in behind using a broom handle as suggested by fixer1234.  Since I didn't want to get wet concrete on the driveway I used a garbage bag and some masking tape to mask off the area surrounding the hole so I could just pour the concrete and push it into place with my forms (you can still see a bit of it left behind in the finished picture).

Some complications/gotchas that I encountered:
1. The pavement around the step wasn't entirely flat, so it was difficult to get the wood forms to line up squarely and stay in place.  I ended up putting a couple bricks behind to push them into place and hold them there.
2. The concrete mix I bought was more granular than I would have liked, with lots of large stones in it which made it hard to get a smooth surface.

The fix is still holding well, and I think it turned out reasonable given that I've never mixed or poured concrete before :).  Now I'm working on cleaning up all the rust and re-painting the railing.

[image: Finished!]

Comment: And, thank you for reporting on your solution, and glad it worked.